# Dynamic Textviews gets shown in each other

Tags: android

Currently I'm dynamicly adding editexts to my app but the text gets in each other. But the problem is that i can't just simply set them to wrap_content from where I am adding them (java side).

I tried setting the properties to certain types but to no avail.I just need to need what to set it to since I've trying for hours, but sure there is someone maybe who knows.

```
//adding the view
lLayout.addView(rowTextView);
//here is where I am stuck
lLayout.set....
```

MY XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout_dynamic"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_color"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".PostworkoutActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/postworkout">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/header_name"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/stopwatch_black" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="Post-workout"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.39" />



        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/dynamic_trainingen_content"
            android:layout_width="405dp"
            android:layout_height="349dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please show the xml file where you are adding the views

Comment: edited question with xml

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following code to the view on which you want to set `wrap_content`

```
yourView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Hope this works!

Answer (score 0):

ConstraintLayout is a generic ViewGroup. If you add a view to it dynamically, that view will be drawn on top of other views in the layout.

I recommend to create a LinearLayout in xml inside your ConstraintLayout (with the corresponding constraints) and add your dynamic views to that linear layout. That way, the views will appear on the right place, between the other views.